# Changing columns name of a df in only one step

Tags: r, datatable, multiple-columns, rename

I just created a data frame from a set of datas (let's call it "rf1") today.
Here is the df

```
df<- matrix(0,1052,156)
```

As you can see there is no names for the 156 columns.
I would like to know if there is a method to change all the names of columns of my df with the names of my rf1 which has the exact same number of col and rows...

I know the old way but I don't want to pass 3h to write all the columns names in a vec...

And same question for the rows !

Comment: You mean: `names(df) = names(rf1)`?

Comment: Be careful. What you have is not a data frame, but a matrix. These are not the same thing. If you want to replace the column names of a matrix _or_ a data frame with the column names of a data frame _or_ a matrix, use `colnames(df) <- colnames(rf1)`

Comment: Look at `set_colnames` and `set_rownames` from the `magrittr` package

Comment: yes it went well !